# Create a github app programmatically without user interaction?

Tags: github, github-api, github-app

Like the title mentions, I have checked the following resources :

- https://developer.github.com/v3/apps/#create-a-github-app-from-a-manifest
- https://developer.github.com/apps/building-github-apps/creating-github-apps-from-a-manifest/

And it seems that a manual user interaction is required to create the app as it requires redirecting people to GitHub to create a new GitHub App.

Comment: Any chance you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Probot cli let you create a Github app through cli commands.

try this:
https://probot.github.io/docs/development/